# window resize did not work two way data binding in angular2 view not updated

Tags: angularjs, angular

Dynamically attach element in the view using ***ngFor**. when i push value to array of object view updated. After resize the window. when i push value to array of object view not updated.

Comment: Information is incomplete.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: automatically *ngFor not updated when i push object to array.

Comment: dynamically attach element in the view using *ngFor. when i push value to array of object view updated. After resize the window. when i push value to array of object view not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use ChangeDetectorRef.

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
//after array is updated
this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: what is `ChangeDetectorRef` ?